# Printing a list with separators

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=''):

    for values in my_list:
        dashed_list = sep + values
        print(dashed_list)

str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
str_list2 = ['r', 'e', 'd']
string = list_function.to_string(str_list1)
print("List is:", string)
string = list_function.to_string(str_list1, sep='-')
print("List is:", string)
```

the out put is:

```
List is: ringing
List is: r-i-n-g-i-n-g
```

but i want :

```
List is: r, i, n, g, i, n, g
List is: r-i-n-g-i-n-g
```

Comment: You're forgetting a `sep=', '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a built in function for this - `str.join`

```
str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']

string = ', '.join(str_list1)
print("List is:", string)
string = '-'.join(str_list1)
print("List is:", string)
```

Or in your function, replace the loop

```
return sep.join(my_list)
```

But anyway, you have a default parameter of an empty space separator... If you want comma+space, you need to pass that as your separator

```
 list_function.to_string(str_list1, sep=', ')
```

If you cannot join

```
new_str = "" 
for i, v in enumerate(my_list): 
    new_str += v
    if i < len(my_list):
        new_str += sep
return new_str
```

Comment: i tried that but can't it be done without the builtin function I tried with concatenation and the display is:

Comment: def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    new_str = ""
    for values in my_list:
        dash_list = values + sep
        new_str += dash_list
    return new_str

Comment: List is: r, i, n, g, i, n, g, 
List is: r-i-n-g-i-n-g-

Comment: so is there way to limit the seperator?

Comment: Sure. You could use `rstrip()`to remove it

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly rather than using any builtin methods

def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):

```
new_str = " "

for i in range(length(my_list)):
    if i == length(my_list)-1:
        sep=''
    new_str = new_str + my_list[i] + sep

return new_str
```